# Hide Multiple UILabels At Once

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have about 20 UILabels that I'd like to set hidden at once. I know it can be done setting an IB Outlet to each label then calling labelOne.hidden = YES; for each UILabel but I would think there has to be a better way.

I tried setting each UILabel to one IB Outlet Collection but you can not call hidden on the Outlet Collection. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. You can set `hidden`:

   ```
   [self.labelsCollection setValue:@true forKey:@"hidden"];
   ```

   Note, that's `@true`/`@false`, not `true`/`false`.
2. You can also iterate through your outlet collection:

   ```
   for (UILabel *label in self.labelsCollection) {
       label.hidden = true;
   }
   ```
3. You can make these subviews of some `UIView` and then hide that parent view.